# UIScrollview stops working when I exit then enter view

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

having a bit of a strange issue at the moment and wondered if I could find any help here regarding it. I'm using ECSlidingview controller as a swipe from left navigation for my application. I am using auto-layout and I am loading my scrollviews like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    thirdScrolliPhone.contentSize=CGSizeMake(294,1400);
}
```

This works great and my scrollview works, however when I use the sliding navigation to change to another view controller suddenly the scrollviews stop working, including the one which had previously worked.

I've found a video on youtube of a user who has the same problem as me - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LktaCZhBu4E

Any ideas?

Comment: A couple of typos make the problem unclear. Are you saying that they work until you swipe away to another view and then when you return to the view that contains the scrollviews, they no longer work?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Apologies for the typos. The first time that I enter into any of the views - the scrollbars work, but any time that they are re-loaded the break.

Comment: Sounds like it could be an issue with using `CGSizeMake` in a view using `autoLayout`. Have you tried using `autoLayout` to define the `UIScrollView`?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how I could do that? I've used Apples 6.0 release docs and tried but cannot get the scrollview to work at all using their method